# Slim protect callables

Tags: php, function, closures, slim, php-closures

In Slim Framework, there is a `protect` function that wraps callables within a function (i.e. another callable). The description in [the manual](http://docs.slimframework.com/#DI-Overview) says:

> What if you want to literally store a closure as the raw value and not have it invoked? You can do that like this:
>
> ```
> $app->myClosure = $app->container->protect(function () {});
> ```

Looking into the source code, I see this:

```
/**
 * Protect closure from being directly invoked
 * @param  Closure $callable A closure to keep from being invoked and evaluated
 * @return Closure
 */
public function protect(\Closure $callable)
{
    return function () use ($callable) {
        return $callable;
    };
}
```

I'm wondering what the point of that is. Here I did my own test:

```
$foo = function() {
    echo "Hello";
};

$bar = function () use ($foo) {
    return $foo;
};

var_dump($foo);
var_dump($bar);
```

This is what I got:

```
object(Closure)#1 (0) {
}
object(Closure)#2 (1) {
  ["static"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["foo"]=>
    object(Closure)#1 (0) {
    }
  }
}
```

I can call `$bar()` to return the callable but why would I do that if I can just use `$foo`? Can someone please explain the purpose of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all about closures being invoked on runtime. The point of it becomes apparent when you need to use a callback (pass a closure as callable `\Closure` to another function) without immediately invoking it.

Let's look what happens inside our Slim run.

So if we simply assign a closure to a resource, like so

```
$app->foo = function () {
    return 'invoked foo returns this string';
};
```

or as a Slims singleton resource

```
$app->container->singleton('foo', function () {
    return 'invoked foo returns this string';
});
```

it will be invoked on each call or on our first call to it, respectively ... so

```
$app->foo;
```

will return the string `invoked foo returns this string`.

Lets say that we want another function to use our callable (as some kind of middle layer) and wants to invoke it with `call_user_function()`. So we don't want to pass in the invoked function (which will be passing the returned value), but rather an uninvoked closure, which we achieve by assigning the closure to a variable/resource using the `protect()` method

```
$app->bar = $app->container->protect(function () {
    return 'bar returns a callable closure';
});
```

And for a demonstration let's pass our `$app->foo` and `$app->bar` to `call_user_function()`:

```
call_user_func($app->foo);
```

will throw an error

```
"call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
 function 'invoked foo returns this string' not found or invalid function name"
```

because it tries to invoke the returned string, where

```
call_user_func($app->bar);
```

calls the closure saved in `$app->bar` and returns its return string, like so:

```
"bar returns a callable closure"
```

I hope this example illustrates the usefulness of Slim's `protect()` method.